# Jquery insertBefore and fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to animate my table rows with jquery fadeIn. This is following peiece of code which i have written so far. please tell me where i am mistaken.

```
$("#insert_heading").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#first_msg")) {
        $("#first_msg").fadeOut(500, function () {
            $("#first_msg").remove();
        });
    }
    if (heading_count >= 6) {
        alert("you cannot create more than 6 headings");
        return false;;
    }

    var heading_html = "";
    heading_count++;

    heading_html += '<tr class="heading" id="row_' + heading_count + '">';
    heading_html += '<td align="left">&nbsp;Heading ' + heading_count + ':</td>';
    heading_html += '<td colspan="3" align="left" valign="middle">';
    heading_html += '<input type="text" name="h_' + heading_count + '" class="input validate[required] text-input"/>';
    heading_html += '<td align="left" class="heading_delete">';
    heading_html += '<a href="#" id="del_' + heading_count + '"><img width="16" height="16" title="Delete" src="images/delete_heading.png"></a></td>';
    heading_html += '</td>';
    heading_html += '</tr>';

    $(heading_html).insertBefore("#submit_button").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML, and provide a demo of your code-so-far at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar. Remember: We're looking for [SSCCE (Short Self-Contained Correct/Compilable Example)](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The problem is fadein effect is not working...

Comment: I am a newb, i don't have account on jsfiddle :(

Comment: But if you *want* one just hit the `Login/Sign up` button on the top right of the screen and then register.

Comment: I was going to try and setup a jsfiddle for you, and for others to attempt to help you as you're obv inexperienced at doing so. But a few things confuse me. 1) If you're creating table rows (tr) and you're tring to `insertBefore` a submit button, does that mean your submit button is inside the `table`? 2) Is `#first_msg` also inside that table? This would be alot easier if you show your initial HTML as @DavidThomas already said!

Comment: @Jamiec yes both are inside the table

Comment: @DavidThomas got account there

Comment: Well they shouldn't be; the only elements that should appear directly inside a table would be `tbody`, `thead` or `tr`.

Comment: ok, so how does this link with fadeIn issue?

Comment: @mfn: awesome. So there's a demo? (Click on 'save' and, once the window's re-loaded and the URL's changed to `jsfiddle.net/<yourUserName>/stringOfChars`, copy that URL here so we can go and see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of you providing the HTML you're using, I think the main problem with your `fadeIn` code is that you've already added the element, and it's visible already, so the `fadeIn` has no effect.

I managed to get this working by switching round the order of execution slightly. Rather than use `insertBefore`, I used `append` and chained the `fadeIn` to the creation of the new `tr` element:

```
$('table').append($(heading_html).fadeIn("slow"));
```

This can be seen demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/HZwvA/

Comment: Still i am not using insertBefore and fadeIn, but I have achieved what I wanted to do. But thanks alot for helping me alot. It really worths..